# no visible @interface for declares the selector errors

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I'm getting No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'viewDidLoad' on 
the lines:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
```

UIViewControllerHUB.m

```
#import "UIViewControllerHUB.h"

@interface UIViewControllerHUB ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *subItems;
@end

@implementation UIViewControllerHUB

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://conecode.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

UIViewControllerHUB.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIViewControllerHUB : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewWeb;

@end
```

How can I fix this?

---

EVERYTHING ABOVE IS NOW RESOLVED.

New error below:

Now getting 'No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'loadRequest:'
on line

```
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please make a new question; don't edit your old one. In this case, you might want to review your code first and look around for similar errors in other questions.

Comment: your code is correct. Only problem is in your LoadRequest method which is not UIView method but it is UIWebView. I have updated the answer please follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code  **'No visible @interface for `UIView` declares the selector 'loadRequest:' on line** why you are getting this error is becuase `loadRequest` is not the method of `UIView`. But in-spite of that it is the method of `UIWebView`. For more refer this [UIWebView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest%3a) . So just replace `UIView` to `UIWebView` and check

//Comment this

```
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewWeb;
```

//Modify this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
```

Note:- **As you have created outlet of `UIView`. So delete the same and drag-drop UIWebView and then  reconnect the `outlet` to `UIWebView`**

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is a `UIViewController` method.  To fix it, change to inherit from that:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIViewControllerHUB : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewWeb;

@end
```

Comment: Also consider renaming your class, by convention the `UI` prefix is for UIKit classes only.